# What is the effect of deleting a branch in gerrit

Tags: gerrit

What I would like to achieve is that no longer used (feature) branches in gerrit are blocked for the submission of new changes and patches.

The gerrit documentation just says how to do it, but not what the effect is (or I did not see it).

I could try to find out by running a few experiments, but that will not necessarily give me the full picture. Can someone point me to more documentation or tell me from experience and/or insight into the codebase?

Possible effects could be:

1. No more pushes to refs/for/deletedBranch allowed (certainly)
2. Branch removed from underlying git repo (I guess not)
3. Not yet merged changes posted to refs/for/deletedBranch disappear (hopefully not, there should be a guard against this case)
4. Already submitted/merged changes and their patchsets disappear from the listing of merged changes (hopefully not)

What will really happen?

Comment: Partial answer for 3.: gerrit will not allow the deletion of a branch for which there are still open changes

Comment: Partial answer for 4.: already merged changes and their patches are still listed and can be searched for using the now deleted branch name.

Comment: Partial answer for 2: the branch is removed from the underlying git repo